# Strip Html for specific Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

i have a html string :

```
<td style=\"border-bottom: windowtext 1pt solid; 
border-left: 
windowtext 1pt solid; 
padding-bottom: 0cm; 
padding-left: 3.5pt; 
width: 489pt; 
padding-right: 3.5pt; 
background: #dfdfdf; 
border-top: 
windowtext 1pt solid; 
border-right: windowtext 1pt solid; 
padding-top: 0cm;\" valign=\"top\" colspan=\"4\">

    <strong>Kan fejlen genskabes?</strong> 

    </td>\r\n
```

and i have a piece of code which aloow specific tags :

```
   public string HtmlStrip( string input)
    {
        string acceptable = "img|n|br|tr|td|table|tbody|th|td style strong";
        string stringPattern = @"</?(?(?=" + acceptable + @")notag|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+=?(?:(["",']?).*?\1?)?)*\s*/?>";
        return Regex.Replace(input, stringPattern,String.Empty);
    }
```

What i am trying to do now is to allow "strong" tag only if it is inside "td" or "table" tag. Any Ideas?

Bonus: How can i allow only specific styling in "td" tag? for example only padding-left if i wanted to?

Comment: [Ob Html/Regex link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/15498) (It really ought to be added automatically by SO if `html` and `regex` are added as tags)

Comment: Maybe this can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931470/replacing-specific-html-tags-using-regex